# How does Best Buy thrive with competition from Amazon?

Tags: stock-valuation

Looking at best buy stock recently and it is near all time high, I personally don't go but I'm wondering how is it that they are doing so well when companies like Toys r us goes bankrupt?

Comment: Buying big items like TVs and what not is def easier from Best Buy than from amazon. Neighbors can steal amazon shipments and they won't fit in amazon lockers either. And with work from home increasingly becoming a thing people are retrofitting their home, I guess

Comment: @neubert [Please do not answer questions in the comments area.](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997)

Comment: https://www.inc.com/justin-bariso/amazon-almost-killed-best-buy-then-best-buy-did-something-completely-brilliant.html

Answer (score 3):

In recent years, many stores, including Best Buy have experienced customers checking out their products and then ordering from Amazon. In response, Best Buy had to revamp its approach.

It lowered online prices for many products and became more competitive with Amazon (see the recent earnings release).  It offers customers service, in particular the Geek Squad which appeals to many non tech savvy people.  It also got a major boost from the Covid related work at home trend.

Answer (score 2):

Best Buy has a few niche services and departments that do quite well vs online retailers. Best Buy sells a lot of home appliances, for example. With competitors like Sears, Circuit City, Fry’s, etc. all closing their doors, Best Buy has been able to adjust and profit accordingly.

Additionally, the company has stated recently that pandemic consumer electronics spending is up for them. There’s something to be said about going to a store that has what you need in-stock, right now.

https://corporate.bestbuy.com/best-buy-reports-better-than-expected-q1-fy22-results/

Comment: So how come Fry's closed but Best Buy is still making good profit if they both sell appliance?

Comment: @bakalolo: Best Buy has stuff that's of interest to a lot more people than Fry's...

Comment: @bakalolo all successful companies must be well-run; companies living in the shadow of a giant (whether that giant is Amazon or Walmart) must not only be well-run, but find a niche that **enough people care about**.